# Enforcing data contracts on posts in odata

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

What is the best way to enforce required fields, field lengths, and other validation on put and post requests for WebAPI based OData requests?

I have had some success with [Required] attributes, but in the past we have used [DataContract] and [DataMember(IsRequired=true), on the entity classes, but that doesn't seem to cause the ModelState.IsValid to return false when a field with the [DataMember(IsRequired=true) is left off the json posted to the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the proper solution is to add both the [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] and the [Required] attributes to each data item you wish to enforce as required.